# Python: updating a single item in a list, updates the entire list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a piece of code that should be updating a single item in a list but instead updates the entire list.

Here is the code

```
a = [
  [(0, 0), (3, 4)]
]
board = [[0] * 5] * 5

for solution in a:
    for _x, _y in solution:
        board[_x][_y] = 1

print(board)
```

Expected output:

```
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

Actual output:

```
1 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: your board is made up of the same reference to the same object, `[0]`, when you update the actual object yourself you update every reference to it as well, you can verify by doing `id(board[0]) == id(board[n])` where `n <= len(board)`

Comment: `board[0] is board[1] -> True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem resides in this line:

```
board = [[0] * 5] * 5
```

`[[0] * 5] * 5` replicates the resulting list of `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` five times so that the reference remains the same across the board:

```
print([id(i) for i in board])
[59200896, 59200896, 59200896, 59200896, 59200896]
```

This makes it impossible to make the change individually.

Instead, do this:

```
board = [[0] * 5 for _ in range(5)]

print([id(i) for i in board])
[45118008, 45045120, 43900680, 43899760, 45119088]
```

The list comprehension will create a distinct object reference for each inner list, and the objects can now be updated individually:

```
[
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Comment: Cool. I never knew that `*` operator works this way on the mutable objects. Thanks for this. I thought it was a bug or something.

Comment: That's right.  If your starting object wasn't an immutable `int`, you'll also need to change the `[0] * 5` part accordingly to avoid replicating the references.  It's important to keep object references in mind, you'll come across this issue periodically.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
a = [
  [(0, 0), (3, 4)]
]
board = [x[:] for x in [[0] * 5] * 5]

for solution in a:
    for _x, _y in solution:
        board[_x][_y] = 1

print(board)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Although, I was more interested in knowing the reason behind this behaviour.